# How to open a new window with its own ViewController from AppDelegate in Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

I have made a statusBar application with a drop down. I would like to open a settingsWindow from that dropdown. I have made the settings window with its own ViewController.

The issue is that i can't figure out how to instantiate and show the settingsWindow that i have made. I have tried to follow every thread on the internet without any success.

My Viewcontroller:

```
class SettingsViewController: NSViewController {
   @IBOutlet var ipAddress: NSTextField!
   @IBOutlet var port: NSTextField!

   @IBAction func connect(sender: AnyObject) {}
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
   }
}
```

My AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
   @IBOutlet var statusMenu: NSMenu!
   var statusItem: NSStatusItem?
   var tcpService: TcpService = TcpService()

   func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {

      let bar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()

      statusItem = bar.statusItemWithLength(20)
      statusItem!.menu = statusMenu
      statusItem!.image = NSImage(byReferencingFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("16*16", ofType: "png"))
      statusItem!.highlightMode = true

      tcpService.initOutputStream("192.168.1.1", Port: 8888)
   }

   func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
      // Insert code here to tear down your application
   }
   @IBAction func openSettings(sender: AnyObject) {
      // open settings for ip and port optional port
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not using a modal window?

Answer (score 15):

in swift 3:

```
        var myWindow: NSWindow? = nil
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
        let controller: EditorViewController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "editorViewController") as! ViewController
        myWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: controller)
        myWindow?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        let vc = NSWindowController(window: myWindow)
        vc.showWindow(self)
```

Comment: Why not instantiate a window controller directly from the storyboard and skip the window setup?

Answer (score 0):

## For 2022

1. in your normal Main storyboard, tap to add a new window controller.

[image]

2. tap precisely on the red "X", then the blue circle, and then enter "ExampleID" at the green entry.
3. in your app's ordinary main view controller, add this

variable:

```
var otherWindow: NSWindowController?
```

function:

```
private func otherWindow() {
    let sb = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    otherWindow = sb.instantiateController(
       withIdentifier: "ExampleID") as! NSWindowController
    otherWindow?.showWindow(self)
}
```

That's it.

Call `otherWindow` when you want to.

Problem:

Inevitably you will want to set up the otherWindow in a certain way, example, transparent, whatever. Unfortunately this is a whole topic in itself, but you do it like this:

```
private func otherWindow() {
    ... as above ...
    otherWindow?.window?.ExampleSetup()
}
```

and then

```
extension NSWindow {
    func ExampleSetup() {
        self.styleMask = .borderless
        self.collectionBehavior = [.fullScreenPrimary]
        self.level = .floating
        self.isMovable = false
        self.titleVisibility = .hidden
        // etc etc etc ..
        guard let screen = self.screen ?? NSScreen.main else {
            print("what the???")
            return
        }
        self.setFrame(screen.frame, display: true)
        // consider also .visibleFrame
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Storyboards: String {
case main = "Main"

func instantiateVC<T>(_ identifier: T.Type) -> T?  {
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: rawValue, bundle: nil)
    guard let viewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: String(describing: identifier)) as? T else { return nil}
    return viewcontroller
   }
}


var ssoLoginController: IDSSOLoginViewController?
var myWindow: NSWindow? = nil

ssoLoginController = Storyboards.main.instantiateVC(IDSSOLoginViewController.self)
myWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: ssoLoginController!)
myWindow?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
let vc = NSWindowController(window: myWindow)
vc.showWindow(self)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% that I fully understand your problem, but assuming that you are using a storyboard (you should if you are starting fresh), adding few lines to your applicationDidFinishLaunching method will help:

```
        var myWindow: NSWindow? = nil
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
        let controller: SettingsViewController = storyboard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("SettingsViewController") as SettingsViewController
        myWindow = controller.window
        myWindow?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
```

Do not forget to set the Storyboard ID in IB (in the example above to SettingsViewController)!

Comment: I don't think this code works. SettingsViewController does not have a member named 'window'. Any suggestions please?